# Problem with parameters in @Query repository spring boot with java

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, repository

I have the following problem, I am creating a native query which calls a function in the oracle database.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM RECHUMANO.M_PERSONAS_LIQUIDACION_DOMINIO_ROL_USUARIO(559, 97, 49, '%GILBER%') WHERE 1=1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> callFunction();
```

if I run that from a service, it works, but clearly it can't go those values directly there, they must be parameters, so I convert the `@Query` to the following:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM RECHUMANO.M_PERSONAS_LIQUIDACION_DOMINIO_ROL_USUARIO(?1, ?2, ?3, ?4) WHERE 1=1", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyEntity> callFunction(int param1, int param2, int param3, String param4);
```

and I call from the service like this:

```
repository.callFunction(559, 97, 49, "%GILBER%");
```

and I call from the service like this. it doesn't work anymore, the function gives me an error. The error is with the numbers, because the string works as a parameter, then I imagine that it can be the type of format that takes the numbers when they are parameters, but I have tried and nothing.

I attach part of the oracle function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RECHUMANO.M_PERSONAS_LIQUIDACION_DOMINIO_ROL_USUARIO (
    PID_LIQUIDACION NUMBER DEFAULT 559,
    PID_USUARIO NUMBER,
    PID_ROL NUMBER,
    PSUGGESTION VARCHAR2
) RETURN CLOB SQL_MACRO AS

    V_CONTROL_TOTAL NUMBER;
    V_TIPO_NOMINA NUMBER;

BEGIN

    SELECT TN.CODIGO
    INTO V_TIPO_NOMINA
    FROM RH_LIQUIDACIONES L
    JOIN RH_TIPOS_LIQ_NOMINA TLN ON (TLN.ID = L.ID_TIPO_LIQ_NOMINA)
    JOIN RH_TIPOS_NOMINA TN ON (TN.ID = TLN.ID_TIPO_NOMINA)
    WHERE L.ID = M_PERSONAS_LIQUIDACION_DOMINIO_ROL_USUARIO.PID_LIQUIDACION;

    SELECT DISTINCT CONTROL_TOTAL
    INTO V_CONTROL_TOTAL
    FROM VW_DOMINIOS_USUARIO_ROL
    WHERE ID_USUARIO = PID_USUARIO
    AND ID_ROL = PID_ROL
    AND ID_TABLA = 1;
```

Comment: You like to keep us in supence, because we would really like to know which error you get.

Comment: Try to use double instead of int as parameter type.

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault, there is no clear error, what happens is that if you run the aQuery and the function is called, but when I run the aQuery that have directly the values in the SELECT works, the function returns values, but when I pass to parameters the aQuery, it is activated, the function is called, but the function falls, because in the queries I have I am using the values that should receive the function and it seems as if they were not when they are to be used.

Comment: What I have noticed is that suppose that I divide the function in two parts, when the aQuery is with parameters, it seems that the function if "obtains" them but in the first part they do not exist, but in the second part yes, it is all strange.

Comment: @Mar-Z I already tried using a variety of formats like BigDecimal, BigInteger, Integer...double and it doesn't work.

Comment: For the moment I've solved that with an EntityManager-createNativeQuery, but I find it very strange that aQuery doesn't work.